# Consulta relacional no Parse numa única chamada HttpGet

Tags: java, android, query, parse

bom dia.

Esta dúvida é para o ambiente Android. Eu utilizo ADT.

Preciso implementar no Parse uma tabela Carro e uma tabela Fabricante. Carro possui os campos modelo e fabricante. A tabela Fabricante tem o campo nome. Além dos campos citados, cada tabela tem os campos padrão do Parse.

Basicamente, o que preciso é que o campo fabricante na tabela Carro contenha uma referência para ObjectID na tabela Fabricante.

Objetivo: meu app irá mostrar uma lista com o modelo do carro e o nome do seu fabricante.

Ou seja, preciso em uma única chamada HttpGet fazer o "join" das tabelas, para que o json de retorno me traga de uma vez tudo que preciso.

Observação: eu não utilizo o SDK Parse, eu estou implementando as chamadas "na mão", passando os parâmetros de cabeçalho com as KEYS em cada chamada.

Eu preciso, por favor: Saber como criar essas tabelas; Saber como testar a chamada pela API CONSOLE no site Parse; saber como fazer a chamada HttpGet no Java (Android)

Muito obrigado a todos, aguardo!

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Opa! Consegui resolver passando na url o parâmetro ?where={"fabricante":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"nome":"Chevrolet"},"className":"Fabricante"}}} executado sobre a tabela carro. Assim eu recebo a lista de todos so carros que são da Chevrolet, por exemplo! Ainda não tenho código, fiz essa chamada no API Console, no próprio painel da Parse. Dica importante: Atenção ao uso de maiúsculas e minúsculas. Observe que no meu exemplo nomes de classes/tabelas começa com maiúsculo e nome de campos/colunas começa com minúsculo. E não esqueça de converter o parâmetro em UTF8 ao antes de concatenar á url. \m/